# Official document on the format of the .rc file used in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, resources

I am trying to find the official document on the .rc resource file format in Delphi, but cannot find any.

What I can see is below:

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Resource_file_(Delphi) (indicate how to include a .rc file)
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Step_3_-_Add_Style-Resources_as_RCDATA_(Delphi) (indicate how to include style as RCDATA resource)

But no official document on the complete format of the .rc file, including the comment format, different built-in resource types, etc.

**Update**

Original I think the .rc file used in Delphi should be same as those used in Windows such as Visual C++.

However, to add a bitmap resource, in VC, it is:

IDB_BITMAP1             BITMAP                  "E:\Temp\bar_bugs.bmp"

in Delphi, it can be as well:

IDB_BITMAP1             BITMAP                  "E:\Temp\bar_bugs.bmp"

But IDB_BITMAP1 in Delphi can be used as a resource name and use directly(such as TBitmap.LoadFromResourceName, but in VC, one must define a constant for IDB_BITMAP1 to work, instead of loading via name directly. So it seems they are a bit different?

Comment: That documentation would be found on the Microsoft site, as it's a standard defined by them to be used for Windows application resources. You can find it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/resources-reference)

Comment: @KenWhite, See my update on why I ask? Thank you very much.

Comment: But you asked for *official documentation*, which is exactly what I provided. There are differences in the way BRCC32.exe (the Delphi resource compiler) and the MS resource compiler work, but there is no official documentation on those differences. The resource file documentation is what I linked in my previous comment.

Comment: @KenWhite, OK. I see. Thank you.

Comment: "*but in VC, one must define a constant for IDB_BITMAP1 to work*" - not true. You CAN define a constant, but if you don't, the resource will use a name instead of an ID. This works exactly the same in MSVC as it does in Delphi

Comment: @RemyLebeau, Thank you. I see. If the constant is not defined, then there will be quotes around the IDB_BITMAP1 which makes it a name instead of a ID.

Comment: TBitmap uses a TResourceStream internally. That can load from a string 'name' or an integer 'id'. But both just get cast to a PChar and a such get passed to the external `FindResource` call. The documenation of that function says that the resource can be a resource id as well, which you can obtain using the [`MAKEINTRESOURCE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-makeintresourcea), but in Delphi, that is just an alias for PChar, so writing MAKEINTRESOURCE(x), again just casts X to a char pointer.